# Can Delphi 6 be installed in Windows 7/32

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Trying to install D6 in a W7/32 machine I run into issues:
- Error message on start when D6 tries to rename file in C:\Program Files.
  That particular folder does not exist, and cannot be created,
  due to a conflict with C:\Program.

I therefore attempted an install in the manually created C:\DELPHI6.
That seems to work.

Is this a good and correct way to install, or should I do it differently?

Comment: That's one way to do it. You can also install to program files and add a permissive ACL to allow modification of files in the installation directory. It's up to you what you do.

Comment: I have installed Delphi6 and Delphi7 withoiut problemas on Windows7 Wondows8 and Windows10.
You must execute the install with "Execute as Administrator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try create folder and chose directory to like draw this :

[image]

or try open setting option folder chose show hidden files